# Creating new column based on conditions and values from other columns in a pandas dataframe

Tags: python, pandas

I have a pandas dataframe that looks like this:

```
+-----+--------+-------+
| Age | PhysID | PedID |
+-----+--------+-------+
|  28 |    111 |   123 |
|  26 |    111 |   123 |
|   3 |    111 |   123 |
+-----+--------+-------+
```

I would like to create a new column called `DocID` which has a value equal to `PhysID` if `Age>18` or equal to `PedID` otherwise. The output would look like this:

```
+-----+--------+-------+-------+
| Age | PhysID | PedID | DocID |
+-----+--------+-------+-------+
|  28 |    111 |   123 |   111 |
|  26 |    111 |   123 |   111 |
|   3 |    111 |   123 |   123 |
+-----+--------+-------+-------+
```

Is there a clean way of doing this using some inbuilt functions instead of writing my own? Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Using `np.where`

```
df['NewId']=np.where(df.Age>18,df.PhysID,df.PedID)
df
   Age  PhysID  PedID  NewId
0   28     111    123    111
1   26     111    123    111
2    3     111    123    123
```

Answer (score 2):

lambda functions are good for this sort of problem

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'Age':[28,26,3],'PhysID':[111,111,111],'PedID':[123,123,123]})

df['DocId'] = df.apply(lambda x: x['PhysID'] if x['Age'] > 18 else x['PedID'], axis=1)
```

print(df)